# Changing the column of cell after using find in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Selection.find to find a particular value in a column. After finding the value, I want the value in the cell that is to the right of the cell.

I am finding the cell using find in this way:

```
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=ValueIWantToFind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

I am trying to change the column of the cell after finding it, like this:

```
 cell.Column = cell.Column + 1
```

But it is giving me a Run-Time Error '450':

```
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.
```

How do I change the column of the Cell?

Comment: What do you mean by change the column of the Cell? Move that cell value to a different column, or move the active cell to a different column?

Comment: I want the value in the cell that is to the right of the cell I found using Selection.find. Sorry, have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the cell to the right

```
 cell.Offset(,1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the cell to the right.

```
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Comment: sorry didnt see Pauls answer first.